# How to redirect FileListAbsolute.txt to another folder

Tags: c++, msbuild

I have an MS Build set up to build C++ projects which is configured with file path length as 260 characters. A few of my projects are having long target names which were failing with

**MSB3491: Could not write lines to file Path: x64\Release\{targetname}vcxproj.FileListAbsolute.txt exceeds the OS max path limit.The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters.**

I have redirected the output path and intermediate path a few levels up to the project folders and all the targets are generated without causing the above mentioned error except for FileListAbsolute.txt.
I am unable to redirect FileListAbsolute.txt and it is always created inside default path (projfolder\platform\configuration).

How can I redirect FileListAbsolute.txt to another folder few levels up to the project folder where other intermediate files are generated?

Edit:
Additionally, FileListAbsolute.txt is generated with 0KB size.
if we cannot move this file to any other folder, how can I block generating this file?

Comment: Did you also try to [enable long path support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) in windows 10 as an alternative workaround? MSBuild should carry the necessary settings in its application manifest, but the registry key / group policy needs to be set..

Comment: the build system is maintained by CM team and not under my control.